# How to check if a button is clicked?

Tags: powershell

I have a following LOC in my ps1 script which displays a message with an OK button.

```
[Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($Message, $Title, [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxDefaultButton]::Button1, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxOptions]::DefaultDesktopOnly) | Out-Null
```

I want to perform some operation only if the user clicks the OK button something like:

```
if (Button1.pressed())
{
   #perform some operations
}
```

How do I check if the button is clicked?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a simple explanation [here](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/09/16/4429.aspx).

Basically, you compare the `Show` function's return value with `[Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK`